# Not able to get the screen of contact while converting lead

Tags: leads, contact, lead-conversion

I am facing one issue regarding Lead Conversation...

when i am going to click on CONVERT LEAD button it will ask me to select Account (either existing or Create new one) after that i need contact selection screen that's what i'm not able to see..

Same thing worked for sandbox but not working for Production only

what should changes to be needed ?

**This is what i am expecting in Production (i'm able to see in sandbox)**
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Is CONVERT LEAD a custom button?

Comment: No. it's standard button and URL is - /lead/leadconvert.jsp

Comment: Go through this link and check https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000213430&language=en_US

Comment: this link have only the suggestion how the flow is..same thing working for Sandbox but not in the production..

Comment: Reshma, Please see the edited question..i've added image of that screen which i am not able to see in PRODUCTION

Comment: Do you have a company name in your lead?

Comment: No. don't have !! why ?

Comment: Reshma, Now i have CUSTOM BUTTON and i've build same logic in both case one for sandbox and another for production...but still same issue occuring..can you please help with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is sorted out :)

Duplicate Rules in Activated in Production that's why the contact selection screen was not appearing while converting leads..

Thanks

-Nihar